# Page-specific controller logic inside shared controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller that deals with a pagable grid, used on a number of different pages. Inside the markup for the grid, I sometimes have page-specific functionality that I want to execute, for example:

```
<table ng-controller="GridCtrl">
    <thead grid-columns pager-info="pagerInfo" onsort="onSort">
        <tr>
            ...
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <trng-repeat="item in items">
            <td>{{item.x}}</td>
            <td>{{item.y}}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{formatLink(item.x, item.y)}}"" class="icon" title="Reply"><i class="ss-icon icon-reply">&#x21A9;</i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In this simple example, I want to call a function that will format the link presented in the third `td` cell, using `formatLink`. However, I don't want to add formatLink to my grid controller, since it's only used on this page.

Is there a common angular pattern to resolve issues like this? What I've been doing so far is creating a new controller somewhere inside my table, and adding the function to that controller, so that it can also use methods on the main grid controller if needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about nesting them the other way?  and having the Gird Controller be the sub controller?

Comment: No, but that seems a pretty good suggestion, although, will i gain anything from nesting them that way round?

Comment: Presumably you have an outer controller that is responsible for setting up the items list on a scope that is inherited by the Grid Controller, it would seem to me that the function to format part of that list belongs in the same place.